# Connection pooling on Azure Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm starting to use Azure Storage to save files to blobs on my application. Since my application could be accessing different containers on different storages I would like to know how to implement a connection pool that will optimize resources.

I want to keep the connection open to the different containers instead of opening a connection each time I try to download a blob

Can anyone provide me with the best approach to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple answer to your question is that you can't really keep a connection open to Azure Storage as it is essentially an HTTP connection which is Request/Response based. You make a request to Azure Storage and it sends you a response and then the connection is terminated.

In fact Azure Storage would not allow you to keep a single connection open for a long duration as it is a service and it needs to serve many clients like yours. So if you try to perform an operation which takes longer than the threshold specified by Azure Storage Service, the service will timeout your request.

Comment: It's the HTTP level connection that is "terminated". The underlying TCP level connection can use "keep-alive" and be persisted unless either the server or the client refuse to use "keep-alive".

Comment: Thanks Guaurav / @sharptooth! So essentially I would have to perform the following step each time I wanted to perform an action on a blob (download, create, etc): `CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
_cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(blobContainerName);`

Comment: These statements do not make a network call. They just create an instance of these objects so there is no network latency related overhead when you create instances of these objects.

Comment: Still, that's potentially wasting a lot of cycles creating objects that you don't actually need.