# Performance concern for Azure blob storage

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have an application which loads different blobs from the same container stored on Azure blob storage with the following code snippet

```
        var cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(buildGraphRequest.AzureBlobConnectionString);
        var bolbClient = new CloudBlobClient(cloudStorageAccount.BlobEndpoint, cloudStorageAccount.Credentials);
        var container = bolbClient.GetContainerReference(buildGraphRequest.BlobContainerName);
        var blob = container.GetBlobReference(filename);
```

I'm not sure if there is any performance difference if I execute the code above everytime I want to get a hold of a blob, or I can initialize the `container` once and use the same `container` object every time.

The closest thing I can find is this post.
[Connection pooling on Azure Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531458/connection-pooling-on-azure-storage?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: You don't need to keep re-executing those initial setup calls.

Comment: @DavidMakogonThanks for the response. Do you know how significant the difference is in term of performance?

Answer (score 0):

According to the information in the post you have mentioned, the Azure Blob Storage is essentially an HTTP connection which is Request/Response based, after sending response, it will be terminated.

But as @Gaurav Mantri said,

> These statements do not make a network call. They just create an instance of these objects so there is **no network latency** related overhead when you create instances of these objects.

So I think **it will be no network latency about performance**, it will just waste some cycles creating objects.